# How to get formatted text in gform_notification hook?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I try to save some details of a submitted Gravity Forms form in a post, but the problem is that when I use `gform_notification` hook `$notification` contains the message with merge tags, so it looks like this:

```
First name:

{First name:1}

Last name:

{Last name:2}
```

but I would need the actual values.

If anybody has an idea how to get the notification message that actually goes out please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GFCommon::replace_variables()` static method replaces merge tags.

> Run `$notification['message']` through the `GFCommon::replace_variables()` method.

Source:
https://community.gravityforms.com/t/accessing-render-merge-tag-data-in-notification-message-using-gform-notification-resolved/5609

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't find this method for the life of me.